# unextected redirection un xampp for windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, redirect, xampp

i'm creating a website, before uploading the site to web hosting i'm using XAMPP on windows. i was trying to use Search Engine Friendly URLs, for example:

```
http://localhost/mysite/[something]
to
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?p=[something]
```

i tried this .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+) index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] #and also tried http://localhost/mysite/index.php?p=$1
```

before this i tried more examples but they didn't work. The real problem is that for example if y type

```
localhost/mysite/some_page
```

i get an error (403), using the [R] flag i realized that redirection is: `http://localhost/C:/XAMPP/htdocs/mysite/index.php?p=some_page`

i removed htaccess file and restarted apache but problam persist with some urls

Comment: `^([0-9A-Za-z]+)` won't match `/mysite/something`. Try to simplify that to `^(.*)$` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm trying to solve a different problem, but if the [something] always leads to content served by your index.php, then just send all requests to index.php and let that page use the URL string to get the variable you need to serve the right content (ie the string after the /).

You may need to turn off MultiViews in your .htaccess using `Options -MultiViews`.

The following is what you need in your .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
# Where "/" is the location of your index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA, L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my problem is that i get a rewritte/redirected address as localhost/C:/XAMPP/blablabla

Comment: Ah, simple. You need to have RewriteBase set to the location of the index.php file, ie RewriteBase /